# Converting m4a (alac) to flac using ffmpeg, output is lower quality?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, flac, alac

I'm trying to convert my imported music collection to flac for compatibility reasons. Anyway, I'm converting using this command:
`ffmpeg -i file.m4a file.flac`
Now technically, this works fine, and converts the file to flac, but studying the output I notice that the original file (in this one example, the actual number varies between tracks) shows this for the audio stream:
`Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 968 kb/s (default)`
and the new flac version shows this for the audio stream:
`Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)`
I notice two things: the first is that "s16p" was changed to "s16" though I don't know what that means, and don't care too much, but what bothers me, is the massive lowering of the bitrate! From 968 down to 128. Now, each track has a slightly different bitrate, but they all end up outputting to 128. Is this a limitation of flac? And if not, then how do I instruct ffmpeg to output at the original bitrate?

Also, if it affects the quality, then what are s16 and s16p referring to?

EDIT: I technically got what I was looking for, though I still don't know what s16 means, and I'm not 100% sure that what I did worked properly, check my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pay heed to the bitrate shown for the output during conversion - that is germane only when the encoder's rate control method targets a bitrate. The FLAC encoder doesn't. Run ffprobe on the output file after it has been generated. It will show the actual encoded bitrate.

FLAC is a lossless codec, so irrespective of the bitrate obtained, it will be lossless i.e. of identical quality, relative to the source.

`s16` and `s16p` refer to the sample formats generated by ffmpeg's decoder for these formats. `s16p` means the decoded samples are signed 16-bit integers, with each channel in a separate plane i.e. `C1 C1 C1 C1` and `C2 C2 C2 C2`  whereas in `s16`, they are stored interleaved as `C1 C2 C1 C2 C1 C2 C1 C2`. To clarify, this is the layout and format of the uncompressed output produced by the decoder. The actual data in the files is coded (hence the term *encoded*).

Comment: Thank you for informing me the about the output quirk. In the answer I provided, do you see any problems arising? Essentially what I'm doing is `ffmpeg -i song.m4a -ab 968k song.flac`. Which makes the output show what I want, but are there any unintended side effects from running ffmpeg like this?

Comment: The bitrate specification has no effect. The FLAC encoder does not look at it, so it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I dug around for a couple hours, and found out about ffprobe, and at first I ignored it, because I knew the command I wrote would end up being long, but with no other choice, I present to you my final, working, powershell command. Granted if anyone see's a way in which this may be problematic, please tell me, and I make no guarantee's, but here is what I came up with (this recursively converts all the m4a alac files in the current directory):
`Get-ChildItem -Path . -filter *.m4a | ForEach-Object -Process {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)} | ForEach-Object -Process {ffmpeg.exe -i "$($_).m4a" -ab $(ffprobe -v error -i "$($_).m4a" -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1).replace("bit_rate=","") "$($_).flac"}`
An explanation of what this garbled mess it, to try and help anyone who reads it:

- `Get-ChildItem -Path . -filter *.m4a` this is essentially like a dir command, but it only shows files ending in .m4a. This gets piped into:
- `ForEach-Object -Process {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtensions($_)}` this takes all those filenames and removes the .m4a. Which is then piped into:
- `ForEach-Object -Process {ffmpeg -i "$($_).m4a"` this is just the start of the ffmpeg command, where the filename is passed, and a .m4a extension is added
- `-ab $(ffprobe -v error -i "$($_).m4a" -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1).replace("bit_rate=","")` this sends the m4a file to ffprobe, which outputs `bit_rate=aNumber`, and then "bit_rate=" is removed from the string
- `"$($_).flac"}` and finally, the filename is given to ffmpeg again, but this time with the flac extension as the output file.
  One last time: I can't guarantee that this command will do exactly as intended, all I know is that now the output flac files bitrate matches the original, the s16p thing still changes to s16, and afaik some metadata may be lost, among other possibilities.